# Pandas converts integer numbers to real numbers when reading from Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, integer, floating

I recently started exploring python for analyzing excel data.
I have an excel file with two worksheets, each one with one matrix (with m = 1000 rows and n= 999 columns).The elements of both matrices are related to each other: one of the matrices concerns diplacement values and the other matrix concerns the force values corresponding to each displacement. The displacements and corresponding forces are obtained from m=1000 numerical simulations and n= 999 increments. Is it possible to identify the force values that correspond only to displacement values that are integer numbers? Or, as an alternative, is it possible to replace all the decimal numbers from the matrix of displacements by 0? I tried to read the excel file into a Pandas dataframe, however all values from the matrix of displacements seem presented as "real numbers" (e.g. numbers "1", "2", "3", etc. from excel are presented with a floating point as "1.", "2.", "3." in python).
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change column type from string to float in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-from-string-to-float-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make an example in a smaller scale (*3 * 3*).

I prepared an Excel file with 2 sheets and read them:

```
displ = pd.read_excel('Input_2.xlsx', 'Displ')
forces = pd.read_excel('Input_2.xlsx', 'Forces')
```

Both DataFrames contain:

```
displ                      forces
     C1    C2    C3              C1     C2     C3
0  10.0  12.1  11.3        0  120.1  130.2  140.3
1  12.5  13.0  13.5        1  150.4  160.5  170.6
2  12.6  13.6  13.8        2  180.7  190.8  200.9
```

To identify elements of *displ* containing integer numbers
(actually, still *float* numbers, but with the fractional
parts == *0.0*), you can run:

```
displ.mod(1.0) == 0.0
```

and you will get:

```
      C1     C2     C3
0   True  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False  False
```

And to get corresponding *force* values and *NaN*
for other values, you can run:

```
forces.where(displ.mod(1.0) == 0.0)
```

getting:

```
      C1     C2  C3
0  120.1    NaN NaN
1    NaN  160.5 NaN
2    NaN    NaN NaN
```

Another option is to get a list of indices in *displ* where
the corresponding element has zero fractional part.
Actually it is a *Numpy* function, so it operates on the
underlying *Numpy* array and returns **integer** (zero-based)
indices:

```
ind = np.nonzero((displ.mod(1.0) == 0.0).values)
```

The result is:

```
(array([0, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 1], dtype=int64))
```

so it is a *2-tuple* of indices:

- row indices,
- column indices.

You can also retrieve a list of indicated elements from
*forces*, actually also from  the underlying *Numpy* array,
running:

```
forces.values[ind]
```

The result is:

```
array([120.1, 160.5])
```

To replace "integer" elements of *displ* with zeroes, you
can run:

```
displ.mask(displ.mod(1.0) == 0.0, 0, inplace=True)
```

Now *displ* contains:

```
     C1    C2    C3
0   0.0  12.1  11.3
1  12.5   0.0  13.5
2  12.6  13.6  13.8
```

Note that the "wanted" elements are still **float** zeroes,
but this is a feature of *Pandas* that each column has **one**
type, fitting all elements in this column (in this case just *float*).